# Snapkit centerY constraint centers item above the center Y axis

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, constraints, snapkit

I'm trying to make a custom UICollectionView cell class. The cell consists of a content view and a label. I want the label to be in the center of the view, horizontally and vertically, but instead the label is placed above the content view's center y axis.

I've made sure that the constraints are set, no other constraints are being set, and that the issue affects all views in the content view (I added another view and set its center Y axis as a test, and that also didn't work). I also set the content view and the label's background colors to be contrasting, and have confirmed that the label is not lying on the content view's center y anchor.

Here is how I set the consraints:

```
label.snp.makeConstraints{make in
            make.centerX.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }
```

[image: Here is what I get instead]

Here is what I get instead. Clearly the label is not centered vertically. You can see the blue UIView, which I added as a test, is also not centered vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I used to add my constraints programmatically in this way

```
self.view.addSubview(image)
image.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
image.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

and my image is declarated in this way

```
let image: UIImageView = {
        let theImageView = UIImageView()
        theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ico_return")
        theImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theImageView
    }()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm specifically trying to use SnapKit so NSLayoutConstraints wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Following Code.

```
class FilterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    let labelTemp = UILabel()

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        labelTemp.backgroundColor = .white
        labelTemp.textColor = .black
        labelTemp.text = "testing"
        self.contentView.addSubview(labelTemp)
        labelTemp.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerX.centerY.equalTo(self.contentView)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast and easy:

```
myLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.center.equalTo(self.topView.snp.center)
}
```